# Windows Phone 7 - Canvas vs. XNA

Tags: canvas, xna, windows-phone-7.1

Is there any significant difference in performance between Canvas and XNA?

What I mean: I decided to create a 2D game and I am aware of two possible ways of implementing it: using Silverlight and displaying stuff on a Canvas or using XNA and drawing textures.

First one would be easier in my opinion because it allows me to use touch-aware controls and by default user controls, while in XNA from what I know textures don't have Tap events associated and checking what texture has been tapped each time the user touches the screen is... well, I kinda don't like it.

So, any of you know if there is any PERFORMANCE difference between a game rendered with XNA and one rendered on Canvas?

Comment: What type of game are you creating? If it's a game like wordament or something where there aren't too many things moving at once then Silverlight can be fine, but if it's an "action" game XNA will almost always be the better choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XNA has much better performance than HTML 5 canvas. Anything native has better performance than HTML 5 canvas.

> while in XNA from what I know textures don't have Tap events associated and checking what texture has been tapped each time the user touches the screen is... well, I kinda don't like it.

You can do that in 10 mins with 10 lines of code. Over all XNA has a better API and while it doesn't hold your hand on some issues, implementing those areas is trivial.

Answer (score 4):

Read over [The Silverlight and XNA Frameworks for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402528%28v=VS.92%29.aspx). The first section, **When to Use Silverlight or the XNA Framework**, is clear and straightforward, and includes this advice.

- Use Silverlight if you want a XAML-based, event-driven application framework.
- Use the XNA Framework if you want a high-performance game framework.

There is a vast difference in the performance of XNA and Silverlight.

In WP OS 7.1 you can now combine Silverlight and the XNA Frameworks, but I would caution against jumping to this additional level of complexity unless you have a demonstrated need.

Comment: I was planning to make it all Silverlight but after a bit of research and considering your answers I made it Silverlight + XNA. Imma use Silverlight for the menus + canvas if I really want to add some graphics to them and XNA for the actual game screen.